# Genexus Design Systems no se actualizan en la webapp al guardarlos

Tags: genexus

Estoy empezando con esto de los Design Systems de Genexus 18, y viendo videos veo que al guardar el DS ya se actualiza en la webapp de manera automática. Solo hacer F5 en el browser para ver los cambios.
Esto no me esta sucediendo, tengo que hacer build de algún objeto para ver los cambios.
Alguien tiene idea porqué podría ser que no se me actualiza?

Gracias desde ya y saludos.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que puede estar pasando es que tengas más de un language en la KB y estes ejecutando en un idioma que no sea el "default" de la KB.

Es decir, los DS terminan siendo un CSS que es un recurso que se graba por "language" (ejemplo: NETSQLServer002\Web\Resources\English\Design1.css).
Cuando salvas un DS se genera el CSS en el folder correspondiende al language de la KB, recién en el build se copia al resto de los resources\languages.

En resumen, fijate en el HTML de la app de donde toma el CSS, en mi caso: href="Resources/English/Design1.css porque tengo la KB en inglés.
Ese CSS se actualiza cada vez que salvo el DS:Design1.

Comment: Como estas Gustavo? Gracias por la respuesta.  Vos sabes que no,  hoy lo primero que hice fue cambiar el DS, dar guardar, y buscar en toda la webapp **NombreDesignSistem*" y todos los css son de ayer. O sea, no tengo nada de hoy en la webapp. Luego de hacer build si encuentra el archivo (css, tokens, etc).
Probé eliminando el idioma Inglés y quede solo con Español, mismo resultado, y el css se esta guardando en <link id="gxtheme_css_reference" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/PruebaDS/static/Resources/Spanish/frontend.PruebaDS1.css?20236241034191" />

Comment: Yo estaba con Net, vos estabas con Java? porque siendo Java está pendiente copiarlo al tomcat (https://www.genexus.com/es/developers/websac?data=50444;;) y en definitiva por más que se actualice el CSS, si no se copia al static de la webapp no te va a a andar.

Otro escenario parecido y es si usas "deploy to cloud", hasta que no buildees no se manda nada al cloud por lo cual aunque haya un CSS nuevo no queda en webapp digamos.
Se me ocurre sea por ahi la cosa.

Comment: Exacto!, he ahí el aunto! ... estoy con java - tomcat. Por eso no copia, me hago un bat que lo copie y listo. Gracias Gustavo!